# Browser scrollbars in ASP.net (how to set them)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

How do I set the scrollbars in an ASP.net page dynamically? When a user comes to certain pages on my site I would like the page to be scrolled down about halfway. Is there a way to do this without using Javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One standard HTML option is to set a target `<a name="foo"></a>` on your page. Links to the page would need to be `/yourpage.aspx#foo`, but that would cause the browser to scroll to the target.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for an anchor tag.  You specify the URL as `www.site.com/page.aspx#middle`

Then in your page, you put the tag where you want them to scroll to

```
<a name="middle" />
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Comment: Attribute should be name, not id.

Comment: Both work, but yes, according to the standard, name is the correct tag.  Web standards are such a slippery slope because of of the browser implementations' inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

asp.net is a server side technology so it is not possible to manage the scroll position without using javascript. At least I have not seen it done.

Comment: The method @Anthony mentioned is a possibility but it really doesn't have anything to do with asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Something you might be interested in that I've used successfully on projects before is the smartScroller. You can place this control on a web page and the web page will automatically remember the scroll position between postbacks and scroll there. Check it out: https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140248/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/111704-1.aspx

It does use javascript though. Any reason in particular you don't want to use javascript?